# AS3 Inspectable or Like inspectable for non component function

Tags: apache-flex, parameters, actionscript-3

I wan to know if is there any way to put a "inspectable" function (not component) to avoid choose another value outside of the defaults.

Example:

If we have a

> function goToHome(typeOfTransport:String):void {
>
> ....
>
> }

And I want that only two values are possible to choose for "typeOfTransport": "bus","car".

So if it was a component 
[Inspectable( enumeration="bus,car", defaultValue="bus" )]

But it only functions in custom components and MXML.

I need a way to do in standard code, like when we do:

> X.addEventListener([//he appears only the possible values]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `TransportTypeE` enum based off of [Christophe Herreman's model](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/87)

Then you would change your method definition to:

```
function goToHome(typeOfTransport:TransportTypeE):void {
...
}
```